# User with two wholesale-copied answers with spam links

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

User [Willis Brooks](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/47825/willis-brooks) has posted a total of two answers, one [two months ago](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/82139/27773) and one [today](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/87401/27773). Each seems to be a long, wholesale copy of (mostly useful) text from elsewhere, ending with a spam-flavored link. How should this be handled?

Edit: the older posting was independently edited to remove the spammy link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's your typical spam with an added copyright violation, flag it as such and we'll remove the content and destroy the user account. I'm going through these two now.

Comment: So, just marking it as spam would be sufficient? Does the response to such a flag generally involve looking at a user's other postings?

Comment: Most of the time we do because the next step after verifying spam is to see if the user account needs to be nuked. That last step sends a strong signal to the SE anti-spam algorithms. It doesn't hurt to flag every post that's spam, even the ones that have had the original spam edited out, just in case we're having a busy day.

Comment: Righto. Thanks for all you do.